# User session not maintaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-cookies

Users can log in fine, however upon switching to another page, the session is ended. As you can see in the [gif](https://gyazo.com/93ca9f85fc5eb32c0adc9063c822cd7a) the navbar changes as if the user is logged out, and the current_user is no longer active. on the homepage, the firstname should be displayed after welcome, but it is not.

any idea why this is happening? Cheers.

Sessions Controller

```
class LoginsessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def show
end

def create
@user = User.find_by(email: params[:loginsessions][:email].downcase)
if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:loginsessions][:password])
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  sign_in(@user)
  redirect_to @user
 else
  flash[:notice] = "Invalid email or password"
  render 'new'
 end
end

def destroy
 signout
 session[:user_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/" , notice: 'You have 
   successfully signout!.'}
  end
 end
end
```

Sessions Helper

```
module LoginsessionsHelper

 def sign_in(user)
 remember_token = User.new_remember_token
 cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
 user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
 self.current_user = @user
 session[:user_id] = @user.id
 end

 def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = @user
 end

def current_user
 remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
 @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

 def signed_in?
 !current_user.nil?
 end

def signout

   session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
 end
end
```

user controller

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @user = User.new
  end
  def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #unless session[:user_id] == @user.id
 #  redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/loginsessions/new"
 #flash[:notice] = "You do not have access and have been logged out"
 #end
  end

 def new
@user = User.new
 end

 def create
@user = User.new(users_params)
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
end
 end

 def destroy
signout
session[:user_id] = nil
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/loginsessions/new" , 
  notice: 'You have successfully signout!.'}
  end
  end

 private
  def users_params
params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :email, :password, 
:remember_token)
  end
  end
```

Application.html relevant code

```
   <% if current_user.present? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout, method: "delete" %></li>
      <li class="trail"><a href="/users/new">Settings</a></li>

      <% else %>
      <li><a href="/loginsessions/new">Login</a></li>
      <li class="trail"><a href="/users/new">Signup</a></li>
      <% end %>
```

Index(homepage)

```
  <h1 class="welcomeMessage">Welcome
  <% if current_user.present? %>
   <%= current_user.firstName%>

 <% end%></h1>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're persisting the `remember_token` in your `session` properly, so it probably gets thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. In `LoginsessionsHelper#sign_in` the variable `@user` is not defined. Same problem with `current_user=` method. I think they should be changed as follows:

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
  session[:user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end
```

Comment: Ah, ok! When the user accesses the `UsersController`, where do you set `current_user` by checking authenticating the cookie? Typically this is done in `ApplicationController`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now. You might move `def current_user` and `def signed_in?` to `ApplicationController`. Then, to help debug, can you print out `session[:user_id]` when `current_user` method is called on subsequent requests?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I moved them over however, it still has the same issue. Upon looking at the console after I switch to the home page form the users page, this is the result. [link](https://gyazo.com/27f061eeafc1fa5e240b012cddd71b76). The IS NULL doesn't occur when the user logs into their page.

Comment: Do you have a `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file? Mine has something like this in it: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'`

Comment: Yes I do, it only contains `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_LibrarySystem_session'`

Comment: Can you show your `User` model? What does the `encrypt` method do?

Comment: Here is user.rb (was too big to paste the code in). [link](https://gyazo.com/6be3dcc7383733c544ed9943d3bf343f), the encrpyt method encrypts the token, it was just something i was playing around with, and can also be done through the digest.

Comment: I shall try it when I get back, then you for all the help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: That stored the user.id as a cookie, however the remember_token still expires as it is created, seen here [link](https://gyazo.com/912bff6070510c7f4eee44f6e48e258c).

Comment: Why don't you just put the token in the session? `session[:remember_token] = remember_token`